# How do I change the syntax highlighting CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, syntax-highlighting

I've a blog hosted on WordPress.com, and i purchased the "Custom CSS" update to modify CSS. Now I want to change some CSS options of [Syntax Highlighting](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) provided by Wordpress.com. For example, i want that

```
   [code lang="C"] int main() { } [/code]
```

will be displayed with a black background instead of standard white one. I've added in Wordpress.com `Appareance > Modify CSS` the following code:

```
 .syntaxhighlighter
 {
    background-color: black !important;
 }
```

As explained [here](http://www.question-defense.com/2010/01/10/wordpress-syntaxhighlighter-evolved-no-wrap-alternating-background-colors-cut-off), but it doesn't works.
Any idea?

Comment: Does it work with hex color codes? `#000` instead of `black`?

Comment: Use a tool like Firebug to inspect that element. It will tell you what styles are applied in what order. It will help you resolve conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to not only change the background of the whole syntaxhighlighter, but also of each line, similar to this:

```
.syntaxhighlighter
{
    background-color: black !important;
}
.syntaxhighlighter .line .number
{
    color: white !important;
    background-color: black !important;
}
/* First line */
.syntaxhighlighter .line.alt1
{
    background-color: black !important;
}

/* Second line */
.syntaxhighlighter .line.alt2
{
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

As you're using black as a background-color, i advise you to ensure that color has enough contrast compared to it.

Also, using the [firebug plugin for firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) you can see exactly which CSS rule gets applied where, and which classes are availble for styling. (a must when working on hosted systems.)

BTW: I found the soluion at the [second link](http://www.question-defense.com/2010/01/10/wordpress-syntaxhighlighter-evolved-no-wrap-alternating-background-colors-cut-off) you gave

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but i've already tried this and it color only the background under the line numbers, and not the first and second line background. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: remember, there is no space in the .line.alt1 and the .line.alt2 part - (verifying the obvious here ;) ) - I've checked my solution against [this site](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).